# When should I call custom hook not breaking any rules of hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I do have a simple component with form. I want to use useSendEmail hook which returns the server response (success or failure). Where do I call this hook so it doesn't fire on the first render but only after I get my data from the user and save it in the state?

Expected behaviour: hook useSendEmail is called when the email object contains users input and returns status (if sent successfully or not).

I am aware I need to call hook at the top level in the component, but I do I wait for the data from input fields?

Actual behaviour: I am breaking the rule of hooks.

```
// importing everything I need here
const ContactPage = () => {
    const initial = {
        from: '',
        message: '',
        email: '',
    };
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initial);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = ({ name, value }) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (email === null) return;
        const response = useSendEmail(email);       
    }, [email]);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setEmail(formData);
    };

    return (
        <DefaultLayout title="Contact">
            <StyledContainer>
                <form className="contact_form" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <input
                        name="from"
                        type="text"
                        value={formData.from}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target)}
                        placeholder="Your full name"
                    />
                    <textarea
                        name="message"
                        value={formData.message}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target)}
                        placeholder="Your Message"
                    />
                    <input
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        value={formData.email}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target)}
                        placeholder="Your e-mail"
                    />
                    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </form>
            </StyledContainer>
        </DefaultLayout>
    );
};

export default ContactPage;
```

EDIT:
this is how my hook looks like after refactoring with your suggestions. I am now importing the hook and the method in the top level component and everything seems to work perfectly.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

import { userID, templateID, serviceID } from '../data/account';

const useSendEmail = (email) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

    const successMsg = 'Your message has been successfully sent';
    const errorMsg = 'Your message has not been sent. Try again.';

    const sendEmail = async () => emailjs
        .send(serviceID, templateID, email, userID)
        .then(
            (res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    setResponse(successMsg);
                }
                if (res.status !== 200) {
                    setResponse(errorMsg);
                }
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            },
        );

    return { response, sendEmail }
};

export default useSendEmail;
```

Comment: you can return a function from your hook which you call from inside of the `useEffect` hook, passing in the `email` as an argument. Hooks should only be called at the top level of the react functional components.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your `useSendEmail` hook, please?

Comment: I did just now. Thanks!